# GetCookie returns NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I try to set and get Cookies in Javascript and Jquery, but it returns **null** for both of these methods. my code looks correct but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

> ***cook.js***

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else 
        var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

and my html pages :

> ***fin.html :***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cook.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="setcookie" href="fin2.html">SET COOKIE</a>
        <script>
            $("#setcookie").click(function() {
                // Using javascript function
                setCookie("mycookie", "itsvalue", 1) ;

                // Using jQuery plugin
                $.cookie('myCookie2': "myValue");
            });
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

> ***fin2.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cook.js"></script>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="get" href="#">YOO</a>
        <script>
            $("#get").click(function() {
                alert(getCookie("mycookie")) ;
                alert($.cookie('myCookie')) ;
            }) ;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it returns null using jquery plugin and javscript's functions. Do you have any idea about this problem ? Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Could you tell us what happens when you remove your cookie implementation and use only jquery cookie plugin?

Comment: @sv_in : still giving me "null"

Comment: @Jashwant how can I enable them ?

Comment: [Turn on cookies](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=mail&ctx=ch_ServiceLoginAuth&answer=61416/)

Answer (score 1):

By default the jQuery cookie plugin sets cookies using the current path as the default value for the path. This means that the cookie will only be available on the same page where it was set. If you want the cookie to be readable from any page on your site, do it like this.

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { path: '/' });
```

Also, notice I am using a `,` rather than a `:`

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, you need to also set the path parameter.

Comment: Still returns null. I just read that I should put my files in the loca server so i've moved the folder which contains my files to localhost and it still return "null"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this in Apache/IIS? Cookies will only be set when run from a server. I've put together a quick jsfiddle based on your code at: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuCEC/

You should be able to set, get and delete cookies and see the value changing as you go.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works in localhost with the JS functions but doesn't with the jquery Plugin :-D
anyway it works :-D